# Android EditText truncating after 9k on Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am viewing a large amount of text (web content) inside a TextView, approximatey 17,000 characters long, which is fine.

When I put the same content inside an EditText (which I presume is a 'thin wrapper' according to the documentation), it truncates it's to approximately 9,200 characters on my gingerbread Samsung Galaxy Ace 2.

On my motorola with kitkat it all works fine.

What's the problem? is it memory or gingerbread or samsung or something else? Without knowing there's a problem somebody could lose a lot of data.

Comment: i guess it should be `<EditText />`

Comment: I didn't paste it all, now updated :)

Comment: A bit off-topic, but can you add another character by typing to the `EditText`, just to make sure that there is no length limitation?

Comment: Hello, no, I have to delete to let it let me add. Note, I've updated my post, it's working ok on my kitkat phone, just not on my gingerbread samsung phone. I've checked logcat and there's no errors or messages. Which of course isn't much use as without knowing somebody could lose a lot of data.

Comment: Apparently, it seems that there is device-specific length limitation. You may want to check on [Limited edittext on some samsung devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511629/limited-edittext-on-some-samsung-devices) and [Android EditText unlimited text length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928678/android-edittext-unlimited-text-length). Based on those posts, consider adding `android:maxLength` with very big value.

Comment: Thanks, I searched and searched all night too! that works a treat. All your help is appreciated.